# gpg verification graphical user interface?

Tags: gnupg

Is there a graphical user interface to verify gpg signatures? I got a file and a file.sig. It's clear how to do it in terminal but doing with a right click gui would be more comfortable.

I read it's possible with kgpg but I couldn't get it to work.

Do you know a graphical user interface to verify gpg signatures or how kgpg can be utilized?

Answer (score 1):

You can install `seahorse-nautilus`, then log out and back in, to get some extra GPG related features in the Nautilus file manager. You should be able to verify the signature by right-clicking on the .sig file at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Dobey is correct -- once you've got the seahorse-nautilus package installed, you can verify files by right-clicking and assuming you use GNOME, it's probably going to be the best option for you.

That said, if you have trouble with *that*, you could also check out my gpg/openssl frontend [Pyrite](https://github.com/ryran/pyrite). It's a gui for both encryption and signing and supports doing tons of things that kgpg and nautilus (with plugins) don't.